# Should [conceptual] and [concept] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [concept](/questions/tagged/concept) and [conceptual](/questions/tagged/conceptual) be synonyms? If they should be which one should be the master tag?

Are these tags misused? Does [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string) need either of these tags?

Comment: Seems like a meta tag really, and I'm not seeing how it adds value.  Seems like it might be better off just going away entirely.

Comment: Making them synonyms would remove half the fun in removing them.

Comment: There was a proposed feature for C++11 called ["Concepts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)), but neither tag seems to refer to it.

Comment: [design], [concept], [conceptual] all added to the linked question in an edit 5 years after it was asked. I've removed them all.

Comment: I can't imagine why either of those should exist on SO.

Comment: If you are keeping them...best go with the noun, like most tags.