# Burninate [conceptual] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've recently opened primarily opinion based question tagged [conceptual](/questions/tagged/conceptual).

This is the habibat of opinion-based questions. Should it be burninated?

Comment: Possible synonym of [tag:design] or [tag:architecture], though I could be wrong, there might be some subtle difference. Little opinion as to the burnination itself.

Comment: Withholding judgement before I unleash hellfire on the tag.

Comment: There is also [concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concept). See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189383/should-conceptual-and-concept-be-synonyms

Comment: Now re-asked on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359505/a-conceptual-burnination-request